# insufficient privileges error though i logged in as system admin

Tags: custom-object

In full copy sandbox, I created a custom object(Contracts__c)  which has lookup to another custom object(Inventory__c). When from Contracts__c i try to create Inventory__c from the related list & save the record i get insufficient privileges error. Though i logged in as system admin

Comment: Since you get the error when you hit the save button and not when the page is displayed, I would assume the issue could be in a trigger. Are there any triggers on this custom object? If yes, is the trigger trying to access something using either a hard coded value or a value from a custom setting?

Answer (score 2):

have faced a similar issue previously. as the new page is opening for the object it implies permission for objects is available. however either via trigger or workflow some action like field update is being performed for which permission is not available.